# DirectX 11 вывод текста

Tags: c++, directx-11

На сайте https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-14-simple-font есть пример вывода текста. Как можно создать несколько текстов с разной гарнитурой и разными размерами шрифта?

Comment: Также, как описано в том примере, только указывая разные гарнитуры и размеры шрифта?

Comment: user7860670 да, также, как описано в том примере, только указывая разные гарнитуры и размеры шрифта. Как можно создать?

Comment: так а что вам мешает делать также, как и в примере, только  указывая разные гарнитуры и размеры шрифта?

Comment: Я выводил 3 разных текста и они все с одинаковыми гарнитурами и размерами шрифта.

Comment: Ну так наверное надо было разные гарнитуры и размеры шрифтов указывать?

Comment: Я указал разные гарнитуры и размеры шрифтов. Изменил код по другому, все получилось.

Comment: Предлагаете телепатам угадать, что у вас сделано не правильно? приводите [mcve]. для использования directx минимальный пример сделать затруднительно, но хотя бы куски с созданием и использованием textFormat стоит обязательно привести